# Compiler error of incomplete variable type

Tags: c++, boost, namespaces, compiler-errors

Starting the the error, which is showed by building the following code:

`Testfile.cpp:27:41: error: variable ‘boost::numeric::ublas::matrix_column<boost::numeric::ublas::bounded_matrix<double, 2u, 2u> > op1’ has initialiser but incomplete type.`

Please condider the following code:

```
//! System includes
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
//! Boost includes
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/integer/static_min_max.hpp>

#include <boost/numeric/ublas/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>
#include <boost/array.hpp>

int main( )
{
    namespace ublas = boost::numeric::ublas;

    typedef ublas::bounded_matrix<double,2,2>       MatDofDdim;
    typedef ublas::bounded_vector<double,2>             VecDof;

    MatDofDdim op;
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<2;j++){
            op(i,j)=i+j;
        }
    }

    //VecDof op1;
    ublas::matrix_column<MatDofDdim> op1 ( op, 1 ) ;

    //VecDof op1( ublas::matrix_column<MatDofDdim>( op, 1 ));
    return 0;
}
```

I also tried an different approach with comment the      line `"ublas::matrix_column<MatDofDdim> op1 ( op, 1 ) ;"` and with uncomment the preceeding and following line.

Then it says:
`Testfile.cpp:29:48: error: redeclaration of ‘VecDof op1’
Testfile.cpp:26:9: error: ‘VecDof op1’ previously declared here
Testfile.cpp:29:54: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct boost::numeric::ublas::matrix_column<boost::numeric::ublas::bounded_matrix<double, 2u, 2u> >’
/usr/include/boost/numeric/ublas/fwd.hpp:75:11: error: declaration of ‘struct boost::numeric::ublas::matrix_column<boost::numeric::ublas::bounded_matrix<double, 2u, 2u> >’`

I use eclipse in `ubuntu` with `g++`.

Comment: `matrix_column` is declared in `<boost/numeric/ublas/matrix_proxy.hpp>`

Comment: You were right, it works now. Thank you very much. Where could I have find it by myself? Where do you suggest to lock?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`matrix_column` is declared in `<boost/numeric/ublas/matrix_proxy.hpp>`
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/matrix_proxy.htm#matrix_column